# Function to return elements from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a function:

```
def funky(a):
    c = [4,5,6]
    return c[a]
```

I would like to be able to call:

```
funky(0:1)
```

And

```
funky(0,1)
```

To get the same response [4,5]. How do I modify 'funky' to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the slice method directly on the list:

```
def funky(*a):
    c = [4,5,6]
    return c.__getitem__(*a)

print(funky(1, 3))
>>> [5, 6]
```

Comment: Defining the function as `def funky(*a): ...` will allow you to call `funky(1, 3)` without those extra parens

Comment: What would be the Python 3 equivalent of this answer?

Comment: @Hefaestion: `c.__getitem__(slice(*a))` works on both Python 2 and Python 3. But Daniels suggestion of `c[slice(*a)]` is better.

Comment: you can use also `retun c[slice(*a)]`

Answer (score 1):

Enter slice(0, 1) as a parameter to your function as is. 0:1 won't work ever as it is not a passable parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
def funky(a,b):
    c = [4,5,6]
    return c[a:b+1]
```

And you can call `funky(0,1)`, And you cant't call like `funky(`0:1`)`. It's not a valid parameter.

You can call like `funky('0:1')` Because. If you need to take that kind of input take as string input and `split` with `:`

like this,

```
def funky(a):
        c = [4,5,6]
        x,y = map(int,a.split(':'))
        return c[x:y+1]
```

Comment: How is `0:1` a string if it's not inside `"` or `'`?